# redirect using htaccess based on date in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect to Page not found.php page if the date is less then some date. 
for example,
www.example.com/index.php?dt='2011-03-11'.

this index page fetches data in db based on date for display. if the passed date is less than some date it should redirect to pagenotfound.php . how can i do this using htaccess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to test for the date, in your PHP script ; and redirect, using the [**`header()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function :

```
if ($_GET['dt'] <= date('Y-m-d')) {
    // Redirect to your other page
    header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/page-not-found.php');
    exit();
}
```

Note : before doing this test, it might be interesting to :

- Ensure that `$_GET['dt']` exists, using [**`isset()`**](https://www.php.net/isset)
- Verify if it contains something that's a valid date

Comment: @sekar I think you should use PHP to do this kind of decision instead of using htaccess.  htaccess file were not created to do help with business logic and their use should be limited to apache configuration whenever that cannot be done otherwise.

Comment: @Elzo Valugi i'm new to htaccess so that i try to do everything in htaccess. thanks for your guide.  pascalMARTIN answer was right, but i don't want to show the pagenotfound.php it should be like www.mysite.com/PageNotFound... can i get some more guideline for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be via .htaccess? Seems like this logic is better put in the script itself:

```
if ($date < $somedate) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/error.php');
    exit;
}
```